# Making the python version of a SAS macro/call

Tags: python, loops, sas, macros, call

I'm trying to create in Python what a macro does in SAS. I have a list of over 1K tickers that I'm trying to download information for but doing all of them in one step made python crash so I split up the data into 11 portions. Below is the code we're working with:

```
t0=t.time()
printcounter=0

for ticker in tickers1:
    printcounter+=1
    print(printcounter)
    try:
        selected = yf.Ticker(ticker)
        shares = selected.get_shares()
        shares_wide = shares.transpose()
        info=selected.info
        market_cap=info['marketCap']
        sector=info['sector']
        name=info['shortName']
        comb = shares_wide.assign(market_cap_oct22=market_cap,sector=sector,symbol=ticker,name=name)
        company_info_1 = company_info_1.append(comb) 
    except:
        comb = pd.DataFrame()
        comb = comb.append({'symbol':ticker,'ERRORFLAG':'ERROR'},ignore_index=True)
        company_info_1 = company_info_1.append(comb)

print("total run time:", round(t.time()-t0,3),"s")
```

What I'd like to do is instead of re-writing and running this code for all 11 portions of data and manually changing "tickers1" and "company_info_1" to "tickers2" "company_info_2" "tickers3" "company_info_3" (and so on)... I'd like to see if there is a way to make a python version of a SAS macro/call so that I can get this data more dynamically. Is there a way to do this in python?

Comment: are you using yahoo finance or which import is it ?   https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Yes, using yfinance

Answer (score 0):

You need to generalize your existing code and wrap it in a function.

```py
def comany_info(tickers):
    for ticker in tickers:
        try:
            selected = yf.Ticker(ticker)  # you may also have to pass the yf object
            shares = selected.get_shares()
            shares_wide = shares.transpose()
            info=selected.info
            market_cap=info['marketCap']
            sector=info['sector']
            name=info['shortName']
            comb = shares_wide.assign(market_cap_oct22=market_cap,sector=sector,symbol=ticker,name=name)
            company_info = company_info.append(comb) 
        except:
            comb = pd.DataFrame()
            comb = comb.append({'symbol':ticker,'ERRORFLAG':'ERROR'},ignore_index=True)
            company_info = company_info.append(comb)
    return company_info # return the dataframe
```

Create a master dataframe to collect your results from the function call. Loop over the 11 groups of tickers passing each group into your function. Append the results to your master.

```
 # master df to collect results 
master = pd.DataFrame()

# assuming you have your tickers in a list of lists
# loop over each of the 11 groups of tickers 
for tickers in groups_of_tickers:
    df = company_info(tickers)  # fetch data from Yahoo Finance
    master = master.append(df))
```

Please note I typed this on the fly. I have no way of testing this. I'm quite sure there are syntactical issues to work through. Hopefully it provides a framework for how to think about the solution.